# Equation number in denominator of fraction instead of the margin

Tags: equations, numbering

can you please give me a hint on the following problem: I have a bunch of numbered equations in a paper, however the following equation appears with the equation number in the denominator of a larger, however still fitting fraction, instead of appearing at the margin.

```
\begin{equation}
\beta _2^*\geq \frac{\kappa _5\left(q_H^2-s_L^2\right)}{\left(q_H-s_L\right)\Delta _H-\eta (\lambda -1)\left\del\left(\Delta
_1-2q_H\left(1-r_H\right)\Delta _4\right)}
\end{equation}
```

What can I do to make the equation number appear at the document margin and remove it from the denominator? Searched through all kinds of posts on Latex problems without solution so far. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: please make your example a complete document showing the definition of all commands, I get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...elta _H-\eta (\lambda -1)\left \del 
`  when I tried to complete your example

Answer (score 2):

If TeX generates an error as in your example (you have undefined command `\del` and more `\left` than `\right`) you should only look at the pdf for debugging purposes. TeX's recovery actions are designed to let it carry on, not to generate sensible typeset result.

I don't know what you intended but this runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\beta _2^*\geq
 \frac{\kappa _5\left(q_H^2-s_L^2\right)}{\left(q_H-s_L\right)\Delta _H-\eta (\lambda -1)\delta\left(\Delta
_1-2q_H (1-r_H)\Delta _4\right)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```